# SFMC push notification not opening application

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

- I'm working on an application build in flutter framework.
- I'm using sfmc_plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/sfmc_plugin) for mobile push.
- Everything is working fine for iOS build but for Android build the app doesn't open up on notification clicked on device.

On troubleshooting, I'm receiving the below error:-

/OplusScrollToTopManager(17283): com.twiddy.app/com.twiddy.app.MainActivity,This DecorView@5247399[MainActivity] change focus to false
V/ActivityThread(17283): scheduleReceiver info = ActivityInfo{5161747 com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver} intent = Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1080010 pkg=com.twiddy.app cmp=com.twiddy.app/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) } sync = true hasCode = 146978243
V/~!MCFirebaseMessagingSe(17283): onMessageReceived()
V/~!MCFirebaseMessagingSe(17283): onMessageReceived() for MessageID: 'NDAxOjExNDow'
D/~!BehaviorManager(17283): Behavior found: BEHAVIOR_SDK_PUSH_RECEIVED
D/TrafficStats(17283): tagSocket(185) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/ScrollOptim SceneManager: updateCurrentActivity: mCurrentActivityName=null, isOptEnable=true, isAnimAheadEnable=true, isFrameInsertEnable=true, InsertNum=1, isEnabledForScrollChanged=false
D/SessionLifecycleClient(17283): Sending lifecycle 2 to service
D/SessionLifecycleService(17283): Activity backgrounding at 20570337
D/ColorModeChangeItem(17283): preExecute mColorMode=0,token=android.os.BinderProxy@ec21f2f
I/ConfigurationController(17283): handleConfigurationChanged: true, config: {1.0 ??mcc??mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h838dp 420dpi nrml long hdr widecg port night finger -keyb/h/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2412) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 96 - 1080, 2296) mMaxBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2412) mDisplayRotation=ROTATION_0 mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.127 fontWeightAdjustment=0mThemeChanged= 0, mThemeChangedFlags= 0, mFlipFont= 0, mAccessibleChanged= -1, mUxIconConfig= 3468921665126678593, mMaterialColor= 2, mUserId= 0, mFontUserId= 0, mFontVariationSettings= 3226, mFoldingAngle = -1.0, mIconPackName= , mDarkModeBackgroundMaxL= 8.0, mDarkModeDialogBgMaxL= 27.0, mDarkModeForegroundMinL= 100.0, mOplusConfigType= 1, mOplusChangedConfigs= 0, OpSans= 4096, mBurmeseFontFlag= 2, mFlag= 0, mPuttDisplayFlag= -1}
I/ConfigurationController(17283): , curconfig: {1.0 ??mcc??mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h838dp 420dpi nrml long hdr widecg port night finger -keyb/h/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2412) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 96 - 1080, 2296) mMaxBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2412) mDisplayRotation=ROTATION_0 mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.127 fontWeightAdjustment=0mThemeChanged= 0, mThemeChangedFlags= 0, mFlipFont= 0, mAccessibleChanged= -1, mUxIconConfig= 3468921665126678593, mMaterialColor= 2, mUserId= 0, mFontUserId= 0, mFontVariationSettings= 3226, mFoldingAngle = -1.0, mIconPackName= , mDarkModeBackgroundMaxL= 8.0, mDarkModeDialogBgMaxL= 27.0, mDarkModeForegroundMinL= 100.0, mOplusConfigType= 1, mOplusChangedConfigs= 0, OpSans= 4096, mBurmeseFontFlag= 2, mFlag= 0, mPuttDisplayFlag= -1}
I/ConfigurationController(17283): android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity:3999 android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute:111 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks:135 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute:95 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage:2470 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 android.os.Looper.loopOnce:240 android.os.Looper.loop:351 android.app.ActivityThread.main:8423 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke:-2
E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManager(17283): sInstance is null, start a new sInstance
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(17283): Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10451; state: ENABLED
D/~!NotificationManager(17283): Notification open Event Logged for id : (NDAxOjExNDow)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283): Failed to send notification's open action PendingIntent. - Sdk Version: 8.0.9
E/~!NotificationManager(17283): android.app.PendingIntent$CanceledException
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:986)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:798)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.a.a(Unknown Source:24)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.a$c.onReceive(Unknown Source:58)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:319)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:127)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8423)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
E/~!NotificationManager(17283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
D/~!BehaviorManager(17283): Behavior found: BEHAVIOR_SDK_NOTIFICATION_OPENED
D/ScrollOptim SceneManager: updateCurrentActivity: mCurrentActivityName=null, isOptEnable=true, isAnimAheadEnable=true, isFrameInsertEnable=true, InsertNum=1, isEnabledForScrollChanged=false
D/ColorModeChangeItem(17283): preExecute mColorMode=0,token=android.os.BinderProxy@869d088
D/SessionLifecycleClient(17283): Sending lifecycle 1 to service
D/SessionLifecycleService(17283): Activity foregrounding at 20570396.
D/ScrollOptim SceneManager: updateCurrentActivity: mCurrentActivityName=com.twiddy.app.MainActivity, isOptEnable=true, isAnimAheadEnable=true, isFrameInsertEnable=true, InsertNum=1, isEnabledForScrollChanged=false
D/VRIMainActivity: onFocusEvent true
D/VRIMainActivity: send msg MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED with caller android.view.ViewRootImplExtImpl.markAndDumpWindowFocusChangeMsg:1003 android.view.ViewRootImpl.windowFocusChanged:9827 android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onFocusEvent:9540 android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce:-2 android.os.MessageQueue.next:349 android.os.Looper.loopOnce:186 android.os.Looper.loop:351 android.app.ActivityThread.main:8423 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke:-2 com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run:584 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main:1013         
D/VRIMainActivity: handleWindowFocusChanged mWindowFocusChanged true mUpcomingWindowFocus true mAdded true
D/ScrollOptim SceneManager: updateCurrentActivity: mCurrentActivityName=null, isOptEnable=true, isAnimAheadEnable=true, isFrameInsertEnable=true, InsertNum=1, isEnabledForScrollChanged=false
D/OplusScrollToTopManager(17283): com.twiddy.app/com.twiddy.app.MainActivity,This DecorView@5247399[MainActivity] change focus to true

Comment: The plugin you're using isn't an official Salesforce plugin. You should reach out to the maintainer of the `sfmc_flutter` plugin for help.